# Is it possible to toggle divs without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code that shows one form field, segmented into DIVs, at a time, where every click of Next hide the current Div and shows the next:

```
function displayquestion(a){
  $(".questionholder").stop().hide();
  $("#question"+a).stop().show();
}

<form id="TheForm" style="display:block;">
<div class="questionholder" id="question1" style="display:none">
    Last name?<br>
    <input name="ln"><br>   
    <a class="next" onclick="displayquestion(2)">Next</a>
</div>
<div class="questionholder" id="question2" style="display:none">
    Given Name?<br>
    <input name="gn"><br>
    <a onclick="displayquestion(3)">Next</a>
</div>
...
    <div class="questionholder" id="question35" style="display:none">
    All done, click Submit!<br>     
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Is it possible to accomplish the above WITHOUT using jQuery? How would this be accomplished?

The reason is because if I can avoid jQuery althogether, it is the preferred option for my project as I am not supposed to rely on external files.

Thank you

Comment: The basic problem of all the provided answers is, that they're using the view as data. Don't use the view as data, the view is supposed to be built based on the data. Instead, create a list (array) of the elements, and keep book on the index of the element currently shown, that way it's easy to hide the current element, and pick the next/previous element to show from the list.

Comment: For future questions around "can I do ??? without jQuery", the answer is always yes.  jQuery is a javascript library.  It is javascript.  Anything you can do with jQuery, you can reinvent the wheel yourself.  The question you should actually be asking is "**how** do I do ??? in javascript"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your function as this;

```
function displayquestion(a){
  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("questionholder");
  for(var i=0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    questions[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  var nextQuestion = document.getElementById("question" + a);
  if(nextQuestion !== null) {
    nextQuestion.style.display = "block"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use plain old javascript. jQuery is just an abstraction that is javascript underneath the hood.

So instead of

```
$(".questionholder").stop().hide();
```

You could do this

```
var lastQuestionId = '...';
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("questionholder");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById(lastQuestionId).style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM functions to get elements, hide and show they:

```js
function displayquestion (index) {
  document.getElementById('question' + (index - 1)).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('question' + index).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

there are a number of ways you could do this with vanilla JavaSrcipt. one way to write it would be something like this:

```
function displayquestion(questionID) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.questionholder').forEach((element) => {
    element.style.display('none');
  });
  document.getElementById(questionID).style.display('block');
}
```

you can also use `classList.toggle` and use classes instead of setting inline styles